# Exit nodemon when node crashes

Tags: node.js, nodemon

By default, nodemon seems to restart the node process if it crashes.

I would like nodemon to exit if it receives an unexpected error code from a started node process.

Is this behavior currently supported?

Comment: Have you tried "nodemon --signal SIGTERM --exitcrash xxx.js"?

Answer (score 0):

Try a [Gracefully reloading down your script](https://www.npmjs.com/package/nodemon#gracefully-reloading-down-your-script)

run your up like this :

```
nodemon --signal SIGHUP app.js
```

add this to your app.js

```
process.once("SIGHUP", function () {
  process.exit();
})
```

Comment: This isn't a means of exiting nodemon from a Node.js subprocess, which is what the question is asking.  Before v1.18.3, nodemon would exit in response to a subprocess exiting with SIGINT, e.g. `process.exit(2)`.